# Error, cannot convert int to byte[] C#

Tags: c#

i have this Error. Can you help me please ?

```
byte[] memory = Console.SetMemory((garageoffset + 0xb0) + (selcar * 400), 4);
```

The Error is on the " 4 "
ScreenShot of the error : [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An9w5.png)

Comment: Instead of posting a link to an image, you should post the error itself.

Comment: And please make sure you copy the *exact* error - your title (currently) talks about an error converting `int` to `byte`, whereas according to the screenshot the problem is converting `int` to `byte[]`

Answer (score 0):

The error says **byte[]**, not byte. You need to pass an array of bytes, not a single byte/int.

I don't know what exactly you want to pass, if it's a one-element array with 4 inside, use

```
byte[] memory = SetMemory((0 + 0xb0) + (0 * 400), new byte[] { 4 });
```

Comment: @dorian.p Now you're trying to assign a return value of a `void` method (meaning no return value) to a variable.